# Show/Hide 'add new user' custom fields in wordpress admin panel by click another field

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

I have created a custom field in the 'add new user' section using this hook "user_new_form" in the wordpress admin panel. Now I want to show or hide this field on the base of role. Can anyone help me?[image]

when i select "agent" from the role field only then the new field should be visible otherwise it should be hidden

Comment: Hi Saud. It would be useful to add your code to your questoin. Perhaps some client side code can be added to do what you want.